# SQL Converting Int to Date or Char

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

My dbase has date formats in 6 digits with a int datatype ('734503' = 01/01/2012).
I have been able to successfully convert these to char with:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(12),dateadd(dd,(date_paid -    639906),'1/1/1753'),101)  
FROM   vouchers       
WHERE date_paid =    '734503'
```

This gives me the output of 01/01/2012.
But if I search on the converted date in a query like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(12),dateadd(dd,(date_paid - 639906),'1/1/1753'),101) 
FROM vouchers    
WHERE date_paid >= '09/01/2012'  AND date_paid <= '09/30/2012'
```

Why doesn't the conversion take place?  Even if I use a CONVERT in the WHERE statement on the date_paid field, shouldn't it work there?

I suppose my question is how do I search with the converted character date and not have to use the 6 digit date?

Comment: Why not use a date type for the field?

Comment: You probably have to do the conversion in the WHERE part, not the SELECT part.

Comment: @Bart... this is not my database.  I would have built it with a date type... makes things way easier.  It is the backbone of an ERP System.

Comment: @Bart again... if you see, I attempted to do the conversion in the WHERE statement... it still does not work.

Comment: @PuroRock - In the `WHERE` clause in your question, there is no code to do any conversions. The only conversion code is in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: @Bart... the conversion in the select statement and then a date_paid >= '09/01/2012' in the WHERE clause, for instance, does not work... it pulls no results.

Comment: @PuroRock - Conversions in the `SELECT` clause have *abosolutely no bearing* on how the `WHERE` clause will behave.  If you want the `WHERE` clause to use the conversion code, you need to write the conversion code there ***as well***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are comparing an INT column with STRING values, and expecting it to resolve as if comparing dates...

```
WHERE date_paid >= '09/01/2012'
  AND date_paid <= '09/30/2012' 

-- date_paid is an INT (according to your question)
-- '09/01/2012' is a STRING
```

Because of the differing datatypes there is an ***implicit*** CAST() in there.  Effectively you're doing...

```
WHERE CAST(date_paid AS VARCHAR(10)) >= '09/01/2012'
  AND CAST(date_paid AS VARCHAR(10)) <= '09/30/2012' 

-- NOTE:  All of these values are now strings
--        They may LOOK like dates, but they're just strings
```

What you really need to do is ***explicitly*** manipulate the strings in to integers.

```
WHERE date_paid >= DATEDIFF(DAY, '01/01/1753', '09/01/2012') + 639906
  AND date_paid <= DATEDIFF(DAY, '01/01/1753', '09/30/2012') + 639906
```

This too involves implicit casts.  DATEDIFF() only takes DATETIME datatypes so the strings are implicitly cast to DATETIMEs first.

**EDIT:**

Another option would be to CAST() the `date_paid` field into a DateTime, then base the `WHERE` caluse on that.  The down side here is...
  - The CAST() would have to be done on every row, then the WHERE clause applied
  - This prevents any use of indexes and dramatically reduces performance

The answer above does all the manipulation on the constant values, so that the searched field can be processed in it's native state; thus allowing use of indexes.

Comment: Or, better still, convert the INT values to DATETIME values before you store them in the database.

Comment: Thank you Dems, but for the implicit CAST() or CONVERT(), I always get 0 results... which is untrue.  I understand that I was comparing INT with a STRING, but as I wrote even if I used my CONVERT() in the WHERE clause it still wasn't working (again, 0 results).  I can use the explicit manipulation (it almost works, it's pulling dates in October), but need to pass it through a variable.

Comment: Look at my third block of code.  That shows you how to convert the `'09/01/2012'` into an INT.  This means that you can pass in a DATETIME or a VARCHAR(10) as a parameter, use code to manipulate it into an INT, then compare that INT with your data.

Comment: As is, if you just do `CAST(date_paid AS DATETIME)` you'll get something like `CAST(734503 AS DATETIME)` which gives a date very far in the future.  Or, if you do `CAST(734503 AS VARCHAR(10))` *[implicitly **or** explicitly]* then you just get `'634503'` as a string.

Comment: Ok, will try.  I have also tried to convert/cast the INT and dump into a temp table, then select my date_paid range, but it then selects the correct month, but pulls every year in the table.

Comment: As a Side note, different localities in the world see `'09/01/2012'` as 9th Jan 2012, and others see it as 1st Sept 2012. To remove the ambiguity try using the format 'YYYYMMDD' *(`'20120901'`)*, this will always be 1st September 2012 to SQL Server, no matter what internationalised server settings are used.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, If you can, change your database schema.  The datatype of the date_paid column Should be `datetime` or `date`, not 'int' or 'char`.

... but if you are stuck with this schema, then it seems your `date_paid` values are integers where a value of 693596 represents `1 jan 1900`.  (This date is where the SQL Server zero value maps to.) So all you need to do is shift, or offset your search values by this amount.

Assume the date you want to search for is today, 19 October 2012

```
 Declare @SearchDate DateTime = '20 Oct 2012'
```

Then write your query predicate as:

```
  Select * From vouchers
  Where date_paid = DateDiff(day, 0, @searchDate) + 693596
```

Make sure that you structure your query so all processing or computations are done on the *other* side of the equal sign from the `date_paid` column, (as my example shows).  This way the query processor can use an index on `date_Paid` if one exists. If the query had any function calls or other calculations on `date_Paid`, the query will have to read the whole table and cannot use an otherwise useable index See [SARGable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

By the way, I was curious as to exactly where this design (Where integers this large are used to represent dates) came from, and I noticed that this value is exactly equal to 1900 * 365, which would mean that in this scheme, a zero value reptresetns 1 January in the year zero (when Christ was born) which would be cool, except that you can't use it in a SQL Server date cause SQL Server values represent the date as a 16 bit signed integer, which maps zero to 1 jan 1900, and are limited to the smallest value in a 16 bit integer (-16,384) which equates to some date in 1753 or so.

Comment: Thank you Charles... yes, I'm stuck with the schema, would not have been my choice to store dates as INTs.  It's driving me nuts and I'd have no answer for why the INT is used.  I will also try your suggestion.

Comment: It might be because the original model required that the system be able to store dates prior to 1753... (which doesn't sound likely for a date Paid field, but ...)  Is that the case ?